# Hiding UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to hide a `UICollectionViewCell` in a collection view. Although I'm successful when I do

```
cell.hidden = YES; //or cell.alpha = 0.0;
```

but after a scroll the cell appears again. I've also tried the following:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttr = <get the layout attribute>//I'm succesfull here
layout.hidden = YES;
[cell applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttr];
```

I thought this might be because I'm using the `dequeReusable..` method and hence the cell is being re used, but
I have also tried to hide the cell in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method to no avail. Here it doesn't even seem to work.

Why is this not working? How can i hide a `UICollectionViewCell`?

EDIT: Included the implementation of `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.cornerRadius  = 12.0f;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.830 green:0.899 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.hidden = YES;
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    NSArray *interArray = numberArray[indexPath.section];
    [lbl setText:[interArray[indexPath.row] stringValue]];

    return cell;



}
```

This should hide all the cells right? But nope, it doesn't happen.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW7

Comment: @stosha: I had skimmed through the documentation, but I couldn't find anything. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Also I'm trying to do without subclassing any of the provided collection view classes.

Comment: may be cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(..,..,0.0,0.0); ?

Comment: Nope hiding the contentView doesn't help it still leaves the cell's frame and border on screen. And when I do cell.frame = CGRectZero it doesn't work;

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the cell (or cells) you want to hide -- this can either be in your data source or a separate property. Then in itemForRowAtIndexPath, you check the value of that property, and either hide it or not. What action does the user take to hide the cell?

Comment: I think you should correct data source as it recommend apple (note in first comment).

Comment: @rdelmar: this happens on a gesture.

Comment: @stosha: As hiding the cell doesn't affect the data why should I change the data source? If i remove it from the data source it really wouldn't really reflect what I'm trying right?

Comment: Do you allow multiple cells to be hidden at the same time?

Comment: @rdelmar: I had already tried keeping indexpath as a property and hiding the cell when row and section is same, but cell.hidden = NO; doesn't seem to work at all inside the datasource method. and no ,no multiple cells need not be hidden.

Comment: It should. You should post that code you tried.

Comment: @rdelmar: I have posted the code , only thing it doesn't involve check for indexPath but tries to hide all cells which also didn't work. Please check.

Comment: @rdelmar: I added an observer to the property hidden and its again being set to NO internally, is subclassing the only way? I have a feeling it will get messy.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just tested it on one of my projects, and I see what you see -- cell.hidden = YES doesn't seem to work (as it does in a table view). What look are you going for? Do you just want a hole where the hidden cell is?

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what I want. I got it working partially now by removing all subviews and setting all background and border color to clearColor for that view. But this involves reconstructing the whole thing again when I need to display it. Any other alternative?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33507/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-rakesh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since hiding the cell itself doesn't seem to work, you can either add a subview to the cell with the same color as the collection view's background color, or you can hide the cell's content view, which does work:

```
cell.contentView.hidden = YES;
cell.backgroundColor = self.collectionView.backgroundColor;
```

That second line is only necessary if you have set a background color for your cell.

Comment: This solution leaves the cell space available and the cell is also touchable

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way to do it:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    CGSize retval;
......
//for the cell you want to hide: 
if(hidden_flag) 
  retval = CGSizeZero;
else
   retval = CGSizeMake(320,50);
return retal;
```

You can check a flag in the above function, if the flag is set, you return zero sized value; if not you return the normal value. There is no change needed in any other delegate/data source methods. The flag can be set/reset in other places. Once the flag changed, you need call:

```
hidden_flag = YES; 
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

There is no need to change `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: This answer works but for some reason when I do this though I get terrible scrolling performance then if I were to just keep the cell a normal size

Comment: What do you mean about terrible scrolling performance? You may need adjust the height of collection view if it's a issue. But since not sure what exactly the issue is, this is the only thing I can suggest for now.

Comment: I think it's because I'm hiding so many sections underneath but its still actually having to draw all those and do some computations. Perhaps a better solution is just to insert and delete sections

Answer (score 2):

Because when your cell is scrolled out of view it gets recycled.  When scrolled back into view the collection view (or table view) will recreate it by calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.  So, when this is called for the cell that should be hidden you will have to hide it again.

It's possible that after you return the cell from `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` that the framework is calling `[setHidden:NO]` on it. You may have to subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and provide your own implementation to accomplish this.  Or add a subview to the `UICollectionViewCell` to contain your content, then hide/show this subview as needed.

Comment: I understood that , thats why I tried hiding it in the method that you mentioned , which also doesn't work.

Comment: It's possible that after you return the cell from collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: that the OS is calling [setHidden:NO] on it.  You may have to subclass UICollectionViewCell and provide your own implementation to accomplish this.  It doesn't sound like a typical use case to me (eg: I'd usually expect that you'd want to remove the data from your data source rather than hide the cell).

Comment: @NicholasHart: I added an observer to the hidden and yes its again being set NO internally, is subclassing the only way? I have a feeling it will get messy.

Comment: It may be the cleanest way.  The other option is for you to construct a subview to contains your cell's content, add it as a subview to the UICollectionViewCell in your collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: then show/hide the subview as needed.

Comment: I'll meddle some more before I go that way. Anyway thanks. I could give you some credit if you would include your first comment in your answer. It might be helpful for others too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but for future developers using iOS 8+ it's possible to hide the cell in the willDisplayCell method.

For exemple, this code hide cells in collectionView vertical center.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Hide cell at center
    CGPoint centerCellOffset = collectionView.contentOffset;
    centerCellOffset.x += collectionView.frame.size.width / 2;
    BOOL isCenterCell = CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, centerCellOffset);

    cell.hidden = isCenterCell;
}
```

(PS : Tested on iOS 10.3)

Comment: It seems the collection view will swap cells for the same content during animation without calling willDisplayCell: thus the new cell will not be hidden,

Comment: @Tjalsma, wich animation are you talking about ? Are you animating collectionView change with `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` ?

Comment: I created a multi-section `UICollectionView` with a custom layouts. I was looking for a way to collapse sections, accordion-style. In attempt to hide the cells in the collapsed sections, I would keep their frames as is, but hide them in `collectionView:willDisplayCell:` This worked until the cells were scrolled off-screen and then back. When scrolling back, the cells were displayed un-hidden without `collectionView:willDisplayCell:` being called.